# C# WPF MenuItem with image as background programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I'm very bad with XAML, but I just need to create an MenuItem, that has an Image instead of Text.

I already got it working in a way, that the image is presented and loaded out of ressources, but on Mouse Over the image is disappearing.

Could you help me to get this done programmatically? In the internet I only find XAML examples but nothing programatically.

Thanks in advance.

```
        var addOnFrameworkMenuItem = new MenuItem();          

        var image = new Image();
        Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        System.IO.Stream imageStream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("MyProject.Ressources.image.png");
        BitmapFrame bmp = BitmapFrame.Create(imageStream);
        image.Source = bmp;

        ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
        ib.ImageSource = bmp;

        addOnFrameworkMenuItem.Width = 150;
        addOnFrameworkMenuItem.Height = 31;
        addOnFrameworkMenuItem.Background = ib;
```

Comment: This would be trivial to do in xaml.

Comment: You're setting the background of the MenuItem, which is probably not what you really want. Likely the default template includes a style that does something when you mouse over it that is causing what you're seeing. Try the Icon or the Header properties.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jim,

your hint helped me. For my problem on disappearing image i just needed to put the image into the header:

addOnFrameworkMenuItem.Header = image;

Additionally I found out to set most of the style properties on following way:

```
 // Create a style to apply to the button
Style s = new Style();
s.TargetType = typeof(System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem);
s.Setters.Add(new Setter(System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.FontSizeProperty, 11.0));
s.Setters.Add(new Setter(System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Orange));
s.Setters.Add(new Setter(System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Black));
s.Setters.Add(new Setter(System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.FontFamilyProperty, new FontFamily("Arial")));
s.Setters.Add(new Setter(System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.FontWeightProperty,FontWeights.Bold));
            
Trigger t2   = new Trigger();
t2.Property = System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.IsMouseOverProperty;
t2.Value = true;
t2.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty, System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Violet));
s.Triggers.Add(t2);
addOnFrameworkMenuItem.Style = s;
```